# Evaluate an (almost algebraic) expression without the '*' symbol in python

Tags: python, expression, symbols, evaluate

I have the following content in the `value.txt`:

```
2A-25X-8A+34X-5B+11B
```

If I use [MetaFont](http://www.ctex.org/documents/shredder/src/mfbook.pdf) via terminal bash how below:

```
#mf
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2019/Arch Linux) (preloaded base=mf)
**expr
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/knuth-lib/expr.mf
gimme an expr: 2A-25X-8A+34X-5B+11B
>> 6B+9X-6A
gimme an expr:
```

I can evaluate the expression without the '*' symbol between letters and numbers.

What I want is to do this using Python as cleanly and economically as possible but still without using '*'.
I haven't found anything about it yet.
I also hope it is a syntax that can be implemented with `with open`, `print =` and `r`.

**EDIT**

A possible idea would be like this:

```
with open ("value.txt", "r") as value:
    data = value.read()

#some python method for evaluate value.txt expression and save in variable value2

print = (value2)
```

Comment: You want a computer algebra system. The python library `sympy` is a good choice

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I tried to use sympy without the '*' symbol but I get the following error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Comment: What? Again, you'll need use a computer algebra system, or implement your own parser and logic engine for that. python has no built in capabilities. Or just call the external program you are already using

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga So far the only ideas I have is exactly calling mf.

Comment: Ok, that seems like a clean solution, use code that's already written that solves your problem. You can use `subprocess` to call external programs

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ThankX!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205395/discussion-between-diego-bnei-noah-and-juanpa-arrivillaga).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always interested in questions regarding parsing arithmetic. Here is a pyparsing-based solution (albeit a bit longer than you were hoping, and using more than just with, open, etc.).

The first 30 lines define a class for tallying up the variables, with support for adding, subtracting, and multiplying by an integer. (Integers are modeled as a Tally with a variable of ''.)

The next 30 lines define the actual parser, and the parse-time actions to convert the parsed tokens into cumulative Tally objects.

The final 25 lines are tests, including your sample expression.

The real "smarts" of the parser are in the `infixNotation` method, which implements the parsing of the various operators, including handling of operator precedence and grouping 
with ()'s. The use of "3A" to indicate "3 times A" is done by passing `None` as the multiplication operator. This also supports constructs like "2(A+2B)" to give "2A+4B".

```
import pyparsing as pp

# special form of dict to support addition, subtraction, and multiplication, plus a nice repr
class Tally(dict):
    def __add__(self, other):
        ret = Tally(**self)
        for k, v in other.items():
            ret[k] = ret.get(k, 0) + v
            if k and ret[k] == 0:
                ret.pop(k)
        return ret

    def __mul__(self, other):
        if self[''] == 0:
            return Tally()
        ret = Tally(**other)
        for k in ret:
            ret[k] *= self['']
        return ret

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self + MINUS_1 * other

    def __repr__(self):
        ret = ''.join("{}{}{}".format("+" if coeff > 0 else "-", str(abs(coeff)) if abs(coeff) != 1 else "", var)
                          for var, coeff in sorted(self.items()) if coeff)

        # leading '+' signs are unnecessary
        ret = ret.lstrip("+")
        return ret

MINUS_1 = Tally(**{'': -1})

var = pp.oneOf(list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"))

# convert var to a Tally of 1
var.addParseAction(lambda t: Tally(**{t[0]: 1}))
integer = pp.pyparsing_common.integer().addParseAction(lambda tokens: Tally(**{'': tokens[0]}))

def add_terms(tokens):
    parsed = tokens[0]
    ret = parsed[0]
    for op, term in zip(parsed[1::2], parsed[2::2]):
        if op == '-':
            ret -= term
        else:
            ret += term
    return ret

def mult_terms(tokens):
    coeff, var = tokens[0]
    return coeff * var

# only the leading minus needs to be handled this way, all others are handled
# as binary subtraction operators
def leading_minus(tokens):
    parsed = tokens[0]
    return MINUS_1 * parsed[1]
leading_minus_sign = pp.StringStart() + "-"

operand = var | integer
expr = pp.infixNotation(operand,
                        [
                            (leading_minus_sign, 1, pp.opAssoc.RIGHT, leading_minus),
                            (None, 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, mult_terms),
                            (pp.oneOf("+ -"), 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, add_terms),
                        ])


expr.runTests("""\
    B
    B+C
    B+C+3B
    2A
    -2A
    -3Z+42B
    2A+4A-6A
    2A-25X-8A+34X-5B+11B
    3(2A+B)
    -(2A+B)
    -3(2A+B)
    2A+12
    12
    -12
    2A-12
    (5-3)(A+B)
    (3-3)(A+B)
    """)
```

Gives the output (`runTests` echoes each test line, followed by the parsed result):

```
B
[B]

B+C
[B+C]

B+C+3B
[4B+C]

2A
[2A]

-2A
[-2A]

-3Z+42B
[42B-3Z]

2A+4A-6A
[]

2A-25X-8A+34X-5B+11B
[-6A+6B+9X]

3(2A+B)
[6A+3B]

-(2A+B)
[-2A-B]

-3(2A+B)
[-6A-3B]

2A+12
[12+2A]

12
[12]

-12
[-12]

2A-12
[-12+2A]

(5-3)(A+B)
[2A+2B]

(3-3)(A+B)
[]
```

To show how to use expr to parse your expression string, see this code:

```
result = expr.parseString("2A-25X-8A+34X-5B+11B")
print(result)
print(result[0])
print(type(result[0]))

# convert back to dict
print({**result[0]})
```

Prints:

```
[-6A+6B+9X]
-6A+6B+9X
<class '__main__.Tally'>
{'B': 6, 'A': -6, 'X': 9}
```

Comment: Thank|) ! really works and your explanation was also very useful for tracking details during parsing.